# Error: Unexpected "<" in Vite Vue in JS files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

When I used Vue-CLI, below code was run without any issues.

```js
export const resourceCenterIcon =   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-gift" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M3 2.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0v.006c0 .07 0 .27-.038.494H15a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1v7.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-11A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 14.5V7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2.038A2.968 2.968 0 0 1 3 2.506V2.5zm1.068.5H7v-.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0-3 0c0 .085.002.274.045.43a.522.522 0 0 0 .023.07zM9 3h2.932a.56.56 0 0 0 .023-.07c.043-.156.045-.345.045-.43a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-3 0V3zM1 4v2h6V4H1zm8 0v2h6V4H9zm5 3H9v8h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7zm-7 8V7H2v7.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H7z"/>
                                    </svg>;
```

Now, I am trying to move my code to Vite and it gives and error as,

```
Error: Unexpected "<"
```

Can someone please, explain the exact reason for this...

Comment: Usually Javascript doesn't like it when you assign markup to a variable or constant. Try wrapping your SVG in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

[JSX in Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#jsx) requires a plugin: `@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx`

1. Install the plugin:

   ```
   npm i -D @vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx
   ```
2. The JSX must be used in a `.jsx` file:

   ```js
   // ResourceCenterIcon.jsx
   export const resourceCenterIcon = <svg>...</svg>
   ```
3. Then import it, and use like a component:

   ```html
   <script setup>
   import { resourceCenterIcon } from './components/ResourceCenterIcon'
   </script>

   <template>
     <resourceCenterIcon />
   </template>
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-jsx?file=src%2FApp.vue)